# Apache: URL should point to specific folder

Tags: apache-2.2, mediawiki

I'm using CentOS 5.5 and Apache 2.2. I just started to administrate my own dedicated server, but I think that I understand the concept of virtual hosts in Apache: I actually have to different domains (lets call em: www.myDomain1.com and www.myDomain2.com) that are both served by my server.

Now I want to use Mediawiki and would like to use it with the following Url: www.myDomain1.com/wiki. How to I do that? As far as I understand, virtual hosts are only for complete domains, but I only want "www.myDomain1.com/wiki" to serve my wiki-webpage. Here are some important information:

- DocumentRoot is "/var/www"
- "/var/www" contains three more folders: myDomain1, myDomain2, Mediawiki
- I use the Kohana Framework on both domains, which usually catches all requests and wants to map them to one of its contollers

Comment: BTW, the manual: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is very flexible and there are multiple choices of how to do this:

1. In /var/www, create a symlink so that wiki is an alias for Mediawiki.  `ln -s /var/www/Mediawiki /var/www/wiki
2. `Alias /wiki /var/www/Mediawiki` in your apache config (inside the virtualhost).  This is primarily intended for things outside the document root (/var/www), but works inside, too; and it's both fast and simple.
3. mod_rewrite.  Very flexible, can do a lot of things.  Also complicated.

   `RewriteEngine On`
   `RewriteRule ^/wiki(.*)$ /Mediawiki$1`

Comment: Thx for the fast response!

Comment: Where to I put the Rewrite code? Can I put it somewhere in my httpd.conf (where exactly?) or do I need tu put it in an .htaccess file?

Comment: If you've got a VirtualHost, put it in there.  Other than that, it'll work in httpd or in a .htaccess file in /var/www